# Visual Studio / C# - PS script, error connected to System.Management.Automation.dll

Tags: powershell, dll

When new users are registered in our intranet, we have code behind which also adds users to Active Directory, done through a PowerShell script.
Suddenly, last week, this stopped working and the error message I get when debugging is the following:
System.TypeInitializationException
HResult=0x80131534
Message=The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo' threw an exception.
Source=
StackTrace:

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll

The filw seems to exist in the path above ...

Excerpt of the code running behind:

```
PowerShell ps;

ps = PowerShell.Create();

ps.AddScript(script: @"import-module ActiveDirectory");

try
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ps.Invoke();
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    lblStatusMsg5.Visible = true;
    lblStatusMsg5.Text = "Something went wrong!";
    return er.Message.ToString(); ;
}
```

The error occurs on ps.invoke().

Over the last few days I've tried all manner of fixes: reinstalling PowerShell, reinstalling Visual Studio, exchanging the dll file for others.

But still no luck.

I'm running Windows 11. The project targets .NET 4.8. PowerShell version 5.1.22621.1778.

Anybody got any ideas?

**EDIT**: This code has been running for a long time and working fine, but sometime between July 5th. and July 21st. this error occured.

--Mads

Comment: You may not have permission to read the file.  Try running PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng : The credentials sent through in the PowerShell script is that of the admin user, so I'm not sure that that is what's causing the issue.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng : I've gone over the C# coding  for the scripting and it doesn't seem to have any errors. The exact same code has been running for a long time, but sometime after July 5th this error has occured.
The only thing I can think of now is that some error from my local computer has followed along to the published project. But I can't figure out what.

Comment: Try changing : SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;  I suspect the certificate changed.  Using either 1.2 or1.3 can't hurt.

Comment: @jdweng : I suspected that wouldn't work, as the site runs on 1.2, but tried anyway. No help, I'm afraid.

Comment: The certificate probably changed (or is expired) and is using a different encryption method than the older certificate.  What OS is being used on server?  Can anybody connect to the server?  This sound like a server issue that the certificate expired or a new certificate was installed and now server is not working due to the OS not supporting the encryption method in the certificate.

Comment: @jdweng: Thanks for the suggestion, but the certificate was last updated in early may and the solution has run fine since then and up to mid July. In any case, the problem occurs when I run the site on my localhost.
I think there must be something wrong in the reference library.

Comment: What changes did you make in July?  It looks like a version issue.  The code is looking for a library in Net 4.0.  Older versions of Net required all previous version of Net to be installed.  Starting in Net 4.3 you only need one version of Net installed.  So one of your libraries does not target Net 4.8.

Comment: @jdweng: I didn't implement any changes in the project itself, that would cause something like this, But there may have been windows or machine updates, that may be the source - there were some updates done July 13th. But I've uninstalled and reinstalled PowerShell 5 reference assemblies, which is the one compatible with .NET 4.8. <package id="Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net48" /> I've also made sure that I have only one version of .NET running on the computer.

Comment: Somebody may of deleted the old versions of Net that were installed on the machine.